# In Beatrice and Virgil, why does Henry say he sees everything in the Holocaust?

Tags: yann-martel, beatrice-and-virgil

Yann Martel got a lot of criticism for his book *Beatrice and Virgil*. [One reviewer described it as "is every bit as misconceived and offensive as his earlier book was fetching"](http://www.nytimes.com/2010/04/13/books/13book.html). Much of this criticism stems from his discussions about the Holocaust, and his use of allegory to discuss the Holocaust.

With this in mind, I'm intrigued about the following quote on page 116 where Martel, through his main character who in many ways represents him, gives an explanation about why he "see[s] the Holocaust in everything":

> "Well, during the Holocaust--"
>
> "Yes, I know about striped shirts and the Holocaust. But Wall Street capitalists also wear striped shirts, for example, as do clowns. Everyone has a striped shirt in their closet."
>
> "Perhaps you're right," Henry said.
>
> He was irked. Sarah had long ago lost interest in the Holocaust, or at least in his creative involvement with it. And she was wrong. It wasn't that he saw the Holocaust in everything. It's that he saw everything in the Holocaust, not only camp victims, but also capitalists and many others, perhaps even clowns.

There's a lot to unpack in this passage, but my immediate question is: why does Henry see "everything in the Holocaust"?